# Batch Print Visual Force in a PDF

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page that is designed to print a custom report rendered as a PDF. There is a new requirement to be able to print all records from a button. In this case, The page is on a custom object and there will probably never be more than 20 records.    I have Googled this to death and the only thing I have come up with is  but in this case there not multiple page Ids. I just need to pass in 18 sperate sets of Data and spit out PDF.

I am not much of a Visual Force developer. Would this be a case of a wrapper class?  a custom controller or am I missing the mark altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to move your base page's logic in to a Visualforce component. From there, it's a simple matter of rendering the components in a loop for your multi-record version.

```
<apex:page controller="multiRecordController" renderAs="pdf">
  <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
    <c:detailPageInfo record="{!record}" />
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Your original PDF page would not use a loop:

```
<apex:page controller="singleRecordController" renderAs="pdf">
  <c:detailPageInfo record="{!record}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can't wait to try it out. I was expecting a much more complicated solution.